# Enclose within double quotes

Tags: awk

I have command like this, but I need each output line to be enclosed within double quotes (`"..."`). How to modify this command?

```
awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s ", $i); } printf("\n") }' all.txt > result.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("\"")` prints out a double quote, Add it before and after the loop:

```
awk '{ printf("\""); for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s ", $i); } printf("\"\n") }' t.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.Is it possible to print $1, $4 in the beginning of the same line using this command? Currently I am using another awk to print $1 and $4 to a different file
and then merging two files with paste command.

Comment: @user3823859 Looks OK to me, try it.

Comment: But I am not getting output in same line

Comment: @user3823859 It's hard to see the exact problem from your description. I suggest you asking another question about it.

Comment: @user3823859 sounds like you just want to change the first `printf` to `printf "\"%s %s ", $1, $4`. As an aside, `printf` is a built-in command, not a function, so parentheses are not necessary.