# Extracting by keywords

Tags: shell, awk

Input file:

```
11 message1(num:1;name:"ee";job:aaffdfd);
12 message2(category:"dds";num:2;name:"Dfdsf");
```

Output:

```
11,1,ee,aaffdfd,"message1(num:1;name:"ee";job:aaffdfd)"
12,2,Dfdsf,0,"message2(category:"dds";num:2;name:"Dfds
```

This is what I have tried

```
awk '{print $1}' all.txt > out1
awk '{ printf("\""); for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s ", $i); } printf("\"\n") }' all.txt  > out2
awk -F'name:"|";' '{print $2}' all.txt > out3
awk -F".*job:|;|)" '/classtype:/{print $2;next}{print 0}' all.txt > out4
awk -F".*num:|;|)" '{print $2}' all.txt > out5

paste   out1 out2 out3 out4 out5 > final
```

Columns of output file should be in following way:

1. First column - same as first col of input file
2. Second column - number between num: and ;
3. Third column- String between name:" and ";
4. Fourth column- string between job: and ; If it is not present in a line of input file,make it as 0 in output
5. Fifth column- Everything from second column till end of line

Currently I have all the fields extracted separately into different files using different awk commands,then merging all files with paste command.
Is it possible to do with single awk command or in more optimised way?

Comment: can you show what you tried so far? I am sure it will help to understand the problem

Comment: I don't think that you should have posted this new question - it would be better to edit [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29936614/2088135) so that it included the details from here, showing the sample input and the explanation in the comments beneath the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pretty but here's a way you can achieve your desired output using GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '{sub(/;$/,""); print $1,
    gensub(/.*num:([0-9]+).*/,"\\1",1),
    gensub(/.*name:"([^"]+).*/,"\\1",1),
    (/job/?gensub(/.*job:([^;)]+).*/,"\\1",1):0),
    "\""$2"\""}' file
11,1,ee,aaffdfd,"message1(num:1;name:"ee";job:aaffdfd)"
12,2,Dfdsf,0,"message2(category:"dds";num:2;name:"Dfdsf")"
```

The Output Field Separator `OFS` is set to a comma. `sub` removes the semicolon from the end of each line. `gensub` is used here to extract the parts of the line that you're interested in. It returns the result of each substitution. A ternary operator is used to add the `0` if no `/job:/` is matched on the line. Using the default field separator, `$2` contains everything after the first number.

Comment: How will the command be if input is :                                                         11 abc message1(num:1;name:"ee";job:aaffdfd);  Output : 11,1,ee,aaffdfd,"abc message1(num:1;name:"ee";job:aaffdfd)"

Comment: If you understand my answer, you should be able to work that out for yourself. If there's something that's not clear, please let me know.

Comment: In some cases,fourth column begins with [ and ends with ]. Only in that cases,I need to replace it with [ and ]. Is it possible to include that in the above solution?
I am able to o it separately but not with the above.

Comment: @user3823859 I think you should ask a separate question, showing the new input and what you've tried. If you want to refer back to this answer, or use it in your attempt, that's fine.

Comment: If the input is as above (edited from message1(num:1;name:"ee";job:aaffdfd);
to message1 (num:1;name:"ee";job:aaffdfd); )
and output required is:
message1 (num:1;name:"ee";job:aaffdfd);
The command tried does not give output in correct format.
awk '{print $2, for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s ", $i); } printf("\n") }'

Comment: Please don't use the comments to show input or code. You have made a subtle change to the format of your input (adding some spaces), which means that there are now two fields before the part in parentheses. Hopefully you are capable of making the required minor changes to my answer to match up with your new input. I would suggest that you undo your edit, as it makes the answer you accepted almost 1 month ago invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Just used split and gsub to achieve your result

```
awk ' 
{
 sec_hash["job"]=0;
 second=$2;
 gsub(/message[0-9]*\(|\);|"/,"",second);
 split(second, sec_array, ";"); 
 for(var in sec_array) 
 {
  split(sec_array[var],key_val_array, ":");
  sec_hash[key_val_array[1]]=key_val_array[2];
 }    
 print $1 "," sec_hash["num"] "," sec_hash["name"] "," sec_hash["job"] ",\"" $2 "\"" 
}' input
```